# Utilizar variável tipo array que retorna da função ajax em PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho que pegar uma variável tipo `array` do `ajax` e esta retornando corretamente até o console.log(data);
mas não estou sabendo usar a variável de retorno dentro do arquivo index.php.

**Index.php**

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <?php
        $data='';
    ?>
    <label class="label">CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnpj" value=""/>
    <button 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-success" 
        id="myBuscaCNPJ">Pesquisar
    </button>
    <?php
        var_dump($data);
    ?>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myBuscaCNPJ").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "banco.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { cnpj: $('input[name="cnpj"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { 
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })
        })                    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myBuscaCNPJ").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "banco.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { cnpj: $('input[name="cnpj"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { result(data) };
        }
    }                    
});
});
</script>
```

**banco.php**

```
<?php 
    $chave = $_POST['cnpj'];
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456789', 'exemplo');
    $strQuery = 'select * from filiais where id = ' .$chave;
    $dados = mysqli_query($db, $strQuery);
    $dados_array = mysqli_fetch_array($dados);
    var_dump($dados_array);
    echo json_encode($dados_array);
?>
```

Comment: Onde realmente você esta com problema? Recebe alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: o valor que retorna é nulo, e já conferi...ao ler o banco o valor retorna correto. Mas não chega no meu index.php

Comment: Algumas coisas precisam ser melhores explicadas na pergunta: 1) Em `banco.php`, apenas um `echo` não fará que a resposta seja JSON; 2) No JavaScript, ao receber a resposta, você chama uma função `result` que não está na pergunta; 3) O arquivo `index.php` não fez sentido e, aparentemente, você não entendeu corretamente os conceitos de frontend e backend - sugiro revisar. Extras: o quê o console do navegador diz? E a aba *network*? A requisição está sendo realizada? Qual foi o retorno?

Comment: acredito que você tenha que dar um return $row;

Comment: Faz o seguinte, troca o $_POST por $_GET e testa sua requisição na mão. Ex. **banco.php?cnpj=12345678**, dessa forma você vai ver o que o banco.php esta retornando. Obs.: para a resposta ser tratada como **json**, você deve retornar só o resultado do **json_encode**, comente o **var_dump**

Comment: Banco.php testado na mão e resultado ok! Veja a picture!
Post funcionando no console da função ajax depois de adicionado json_encode.
Retirado o var_dump...já
e não sei como trabalhar ou enviar o resultado para o index.php...
Como trabalhar o index.php???

Comment: Quando vc tirar o var_dump e adicionar o **echo json_encode**, vc vai fazer a chamada pelo $.ajax, se a url estiver certa e o servidor responder algo, a resposta vai chegar na sua funcao **success**. eu prefiro usar o $.ajax({minha config}).done(function(data){} ).fail( function(){} ), agora isso não indica que tudo ocorreu bem, apenas indica que foi no servidor e voltou, para indicar que tudo ocorreu bem eu colocaria na resposta algo como 'status' onde 1 = ok , 0 = falha

Comment: o array está retornando correto, mas eu não sei usar no index.php. Tem como imprimir a variável array dentro do index.php? Vou tentar usar da forma que vc postou...

Comment: done(function(data){ foi no servidor e retornou }).fail(function(){ nao conseguiu ir no servidor }), 
estrutura de retorno {data:<dados de resposta>, status:<1=sucesso, 0=algo errado>} ou seja se a query der error vc retorna {status:0} , se tudo for ok retorna {data:dados_array, status:1} essa resposta vai chegar no done(function(data){  data.status,  data.data } )  [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: coloca assim $.ajax({suaconfiguracao}).done(function(data){  document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify( data) ; })

Comment: Icaro, esse comando ai funcionou perfeito e os dados foram para a tela.
Mas eu queria algo que eu pudesse usar assim:
<input type="text" name="cnpj" value=dados_array['cnpj']/>
<input type="text" name="nome" value=dados_array['nome']/>

Tem como? Observe que era esse o objetivo da pergunta desde o inicio e eu não estou fazendo outra pergunta...apenas seguindo para resolver a minha duvida inicial! Tem como ir para o CHAT?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80574/discussion-between-emilio-dami-silva-and-icaro-martins).

Comment: Agora não da, mas o que você quer agora e so jquery, Ex. criar um input >  minput=$('<input>'), 
apendar > $(document.body).append( minput ); alterar propriedades >  minput.prop( {name:'cnpj',value:'12345' });

Comment: ok..Entendi. Vou fechar a pergunta porque o principal já foi realizado. Obrigado! Vou testar aqui os comandos jquery...

Answer (score 1):

Se está a fazer POST  no mínimo terá que obter a variável

```
 $cnpj =htmlspecialchars($_POST["cnpj"]);
```

Comment: utilizei...esta correto até agora, mas não sei como usar no index.php

Answer (score 1):

A saída esperada provalmente que vc quer é um um JSON?

```
 <?php 
 echo json_encode($dados_array);
 ?>
```

Comment: utilizei...esta correto até agora, mas não sei como usar no index.php
Obrigado, validei um pontinho pra vc!

Comment: seu retorno data, é um array javascript, exemplo:   `data[0].id, data[0].nome`

conforme é no php: `$dados_array[0]['id']; $dados_array[0]['nome']`

Comment: Entendi! Eu consegui resolver esta questão com a ajuda de todos aqui. Mas foi muito bem resolvida. Espero que sirva de ajuda para outros!